# 22.04 Input devices freeze when docking station connects

Tags: keyboard, mouse, dell, 22.04

I have been using the release candidates for Ubuntu 22.04 for a few weeks on my XPS 13.  Last night, after the last update took place, my keyboard, mouse, touchpad, and touch screen all froze.  What I learned is that this freeze comes after the Dell docking station finally connects.  If I disconnect the docking station, all is well, but I obviously cannot use an external monitor, keyboard, or other USB devices that are usually attached.

Comment: You need a firmware update for your dock.

Comment: For me, it does not freeze if I select "xorg" on the login screen. Not sure why it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relatively vague answer but it worked for my co-worker.
We sovled it by switching from Wayland to xorg(x11) on Ubuntu 22.04. I think she used a Dell xps laptop of some sort.

Comment: This worked.  My combination is an XPS13 with WD15 docking station and the Dell Ultra wide U4919 monitor.  Switching to Xorg was accomplished by selecting the setting gear on the password screen.

Comment: Worked for me on a Lenovo ThinkPad. The switch was easy: I logged out, pressed the cogwheel at the bottom right of the login screen and changed to Xorg, as described here: https://beebom.com/how-switch-between-wayland-xorg-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar XPS model laptop, and a StarTech USB type C dock. Was having the same issue, and now have a slightly different one.

To get external displays from the dock to work (without the displays freezing) I had to:

1. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS
2. Install dkms `apt install dkms`
3. Install NVidia drivers which I just did from the "software & updates" GUI under the "Additional Drivers" tab.
4. Install DisplayLink drivers, which as I understand it, are required for most generic USB type C docks on Ubuntu. Just downloaded an archive, and ran the script inside it: https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu-5.5
5. Reboot.

My current state has me able to use external monitors via my dock, but my USB devices (mouse and keyboard) inputs are frozen besides the ones directly on my laptop.. Sooo I'm part of the way to a usable system while hooked up to my docking station.

Comment: Nope.  Secure boot has been off, dkms was already installed.  There were no additional drivers available in Software and Updates, but I was able to add the displaylink drivers.  As with HDMI, my Dell 4919 shows my Ubuntu background, but as soon as it comes up, my keyboard and mouse freeze.  When I unplug, they come back to life.  I am about ready to return to 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

What was the problem for me was resolutions which are set after connecting the docking station. In that case, my laptop directly goes to UHD (external monitors are only FHD) when attaching docking station, and then laptop freezez. This mismatch was a problem on my end.

After some weird trial-and-error, I have:

- attached docking station to laptop with no monitors
- attached first monitor via display port
- switch the monitor settings to mirror mode with unified resolution (FHD everywhere) and no fractional scalling.
- attached the second monitor via VGA cable

I would suggest starting with attaching the docking station without external monitors and trying to set the same resolution with no scaling everywhere by attaching monitors one by one.

My setup is Dell Precision 5530 with a WD15 docking station + two Dell P2414H monitors.

Comment: I raised a bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1982658

Answer (score 0):

Tried the first two answers with no success. After reading the third, I looked for how to switch, since my computer didn't explicitly have the ubuntu on xorg on login.

For those who struggle a bit more like me, I advise just disabling wayland and [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop) was very helpful in getting me there. :)

In a nutshell, first enter the config file of the default display manager for the GNOME desktop environment (GDM3) writing the following line in your terminal

```
$ sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Then, uncomment the line that says *#WaylandEnable=false*. I left it as false.

Save, exit, and reboot with

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

Comment: FYI no need to disable it. When you see the login prompt in ubuntu notice that, when you click on your name (user) from the list and before you enter your password, a small cog appears at the bottom right of the screen. If you click it you can switch between "ubuntu" ie using Xorg  or "ubuntu wayland" ie using wayland... also it remembers you last choice next time you log in

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell XPS 15 running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) and a Wavlink dock (DisplayLink driver)

If the dock is plugged into the usb-c port then the system hangs on boot. If I unplug it and reboot it starts OK, then if I plug in the dock to the usb-c port I can see my monitors in the settings/Displays.

I have found that it works fine on intel and on the Nvidia card, as well as on Xorg or Wayland....

... however the first time I plugged it in after installing the DisplayLink drivers after a reboot no monitors were detected in Display settings. After switching to Wayland they were detected but it took a noticeably large delay 10 seconds-ish per monitor. After that however it works fine and fast in xorg or wayland, perhaps it takes a while to initialise first time or maybe there are more things that need to install on detect? just voodoo, but seems OK at the moment.